# Ipython parallel scripts running and return the local variables

Tags: parallel-processing, ipython, cluster-computing, jupyter-notebook

For instance, I run 4 scripts sequentially:

```
%run -i script1.py
%run -i script2.py
%run -i script3.py
%run -i script4.py
```

The time of execution of each quite long. Is there any way in iPython notebook to run the scripts in parallel **and return the local variables from all of them**(2 or 3 variables which are important)? In the sequential execution it works fine but long. Thank you in advance.

I've tried to apply the code from this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312284/ipython-notebook-how-to-parallelize-external-script) but stuck on the first part:

```
def my_func(my_file):
      !python pgm.py my_file
```

or in my case:

```
 def my_func(my_file):
      %run -i $my_file
```

I can see that execution of the code is happening but after this I can not see the local variables from these scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you started 4 engines and you'll send your 4 scripts on each.

After doing

```
rc = parallel.Client()
view = rc.load_balanced_view()
r = view.map_async(my_func, ["script1.py", "script2.py", "script3.py", "script4.py"])
```

Once it's finished, you can access, let's say variable `a` and `b` with `pull`:

```
var = rc[:].pull(["a","b"])
var.result # or var.r or var.result_dict
[[10, 12020.2], [11, 14], [1, 0], [1, 14425]]
```

Which correspond to the value of `a` and `b` after each the run of each script.

So in `script1.py`, at the end, you have `a==10` and `b==12020.2`.

Hope this helps.

---

By the way, I edited a bit the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312284/ipython-notebook-how-to-parallelize-external-script) you refer to, there was a small mistake:

```
def my_func(my_file):
      !python pgm.py my_file
```

should be:

```
def my_func(my_file):
      !python pgm.py {my_file}
```