# Fail to import IPython parallel in Jupyter

Tags: ipython, jupyter, ipython-parallel

I recently made an update of IPython to 4.0.0 and installed Jupyter 4.0.6.

I wanted to use Ipython parallel, and after starting the engines in the notebook, I imported:

```
from IPython import parallel
```

And it fails:

```
~/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/traitlets.py:5: UserWarning: IPython.utils.traitlets has moved to a top-level traitlets package.
  warn("IPython.utils.traitlets has moved to a top-level traitlets package.")
~/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/pickleutil.py:3: UserWarning: IPython.utils.pickleutil has moved to ipykernel.pickleutil
  warn("IPython.utils.pickleutil has moved to ipykernel.pickleutil")
~/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/jsonutil.py:3: UserWarning: IPython.utils.jsonutil has moved to jupyter_client.jsonutil
  warn("IPython.utils.jsonutil has moved to jupyter_client.jsonutil")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5652e9e33a4d> in <module>()
----> 1 from IPython import parallel

~/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/parallel/__init__.py in <module>()
     31 
     32 from .client.asyncresult import *
---> 33 from .client.client import Client
     34 from .client.remotefunction import *
     35 from .client.view import *

~/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/parallel/client/client.py in <module>()
     38 from IPython.utils.capture import RichOutput
     39 from IPython.utils.coloransi import TermColors
---> 40 from IPython.utils.jsonutil import rekey, extract_dates, parse_date
     41 from IPython.utils.localinterfaces import localhost, is_local_ip
     42 from IPython.utils.path import get_ipython_dir

ImportError: cannot import name rekey
```

So I tried:

```
pip install rekey
```

But no distribution were found.

Note that it fails the same way in the notebook, be it open with `ipython notebook` or `jupyter notebook`, and in the console.

Also note that there is a warning:

```
UserWarning: IPython.utils.jsonutil has moved to jupyter_client.jsonutil
```

But `rekey` does not exist in the module `jupyter_client.jsonutil`

**Question: How can I have IPython parallel to work within Jupyter ?**
What am I missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem I think (at least it works):

- First, I had to `import ipyparallel` instead of `IPython.parallel`
  See here: http://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/migrating.html#imports

---

EDIT: I get this OSError, but the fix was apparently useless, and it works without. I still don't get why I had this error, though.

- Then, I had another error, when starting the client:

  ```
  OSError: Connection file '~/.ipython/profile_default/security/ipcontroller-client.json' not found.
  You have attempted to connect to an IPython Cluster but no Controller could be found.
  Please double-check your configuration and ensure that a cluster is running.
  ```

So I just copy the directory `~/.ipython/profile_default` to `~/.jupyter/profile_default`

And it works!

Comment: moving ~/.ipython/profile_default to ~/.jupyter/profile_default is equivalent to removing the profile directory. ~/.jupyter/profile_default isn't searched for any files. The connection files for ipyparallel are still in ~/.ipython/profile_default/security/

Comment: @minrk So if I remove `~/.jupyter/profile_default`, it should still work ? Otherwise, how can I solve the `OSError` ?

Comment: You're right it's still working. Why did I get this error then ?

Comment: The error was just that the connection file didn't exist (the controller may not have started properly, or the file may have been deleted). It was probably unrelated to the migration, and starting the controller again is likely what fixed it.

Comment: Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71721629/2314737) to [ipyparallel Exception: "You have attampted to connect to an IPython Cluster but no Controller could be found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45584619/ipyparallel-exception-you-have-attampted-to-connect-to-an-ipython-cluster-but/71721629)